# How can we generate a finite group by a set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

I've learned about generate a group by a set. I saw some examples of infinite group and finite group that generated by a set. But I come up with a question: is there any conditions or theorems that show us a set can generate a finite group?

Comment: Just take all the elements. (e.g $\{0,1,2,3,...,8\}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: Yes you can define a group operation on any set, and then that set will generate that group.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the group presentation, you have for exemple :
$$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = <\{x\};{x^2=1}>.$$
Your set represent the generators of your group, and then you add some relations to these elements. If you have enough relations (torsion), your group is finite.

Comment: But some of your relations could cause elements in the set to become equal in the group, in which case that set could no longer be identified with a subset of the group.

Comment: Yes of course but you can always suppose that your generators are distincts. Moreover every finite set can generate a finite group and every finite group can be generated by a finite set (where the images of the elements of the set are disctinct in the group).